# Set Div Width 100% But With Margin

Tags: css, margin

How can I make my div the max size of a container? When I try searching it up my self I always find articles talking about max-width.In my website my content area is a div that has 4 items in it and I want to set the width of content area to 100%. To make all the items fit perfectly but when I do this the margin is overridden?

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the following in the style or CSS and see if it works:

`box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: Auto correct must have removed dashes from my reply. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Where should I add it to?

Comment: Or if your `<div>` has a class like `<div class="something">` then you can add it in your CSS file like this `.something { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: This is cool! I just learned about that CSS attribute on stackoverflow myself as an answer to one of my questions.